# Unable to add new script in Adwords since new update

Tags: google-apps-script, google-ads-api

I've been a passive StackOverflow user for more than a decade now. I don't really think this is the place to ask this but Google Developers Help page referred me here.

Adwords has been updating to a beta version and I'm a heavy user of its Scripts console, but recently, when I want to ad a new script with the big red button, it starts loading and then this message displays: "There was a problem loading the script. Please try again later"

I've already tried with Chrome and Safari, a cookieless browser and with a different account and nothings seems to work. I also Google the error and there is nothing. I don't think I'm the only person experiencing this, do you have any solution?

Comment: Is this code related or just tools ?

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't reproduce your problem and was able to create scripts—however, I've noticed quite a lot of bugs in the new web interface (to be fair, they say it's still in beta).

But as a workaround, just use the *Return to previous AdWords* link in the three dot option menu, which will take you back to the old interface. I could well imagine that you'll be able to add a new script there.